# Is there a way to get UIImage file name?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a Sets! game in which I need to choose 3 cards from the `UI` and compare between them (I am comparing the names of the images) for example:

`UIButton` 1 w/ image name : "1123"

`UIButton` 2 w/ image name : "1223"

`UIButton` 3 w/ image name : "1133"

Using this func:

```
func checkingIfMatch(cardOne : String, cardTwo : String, cardThree : String) -> Bool {
        let first = cardOne.compactMap{Int(String($0))} //making an array from the UIImage file name
        let second = cardTwo.compactMap{Int(String($0))}
        let third = cardThree.compactMap{Int(String($0))}
    if (first[0] == second[0] && second[0] == third[0]) || (first[0] != second[0] && second[0] != third[0]) {
        if (first[1] == second[1] && second[1] == third[1]) || (first[1] != second[1] && second[1] != third[1]) {
            if (first[2] == second[2] && second[2] == third[2]) || (first[2] != second[2] && second[2] != third[2]) {
                if (first[3] == second[3] && second[3] == third[3]) || (first[3] != second[3] && second[3] != third[3]) {
                    print("match!")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print("no match!")
    return false
}
```

}

I am trying to get the name of the `UIButton`'s image when tapping on the button in order to do it but seems like I cant find a way to do it. 
Any help will be appreciated, if there is no way to do it would like to hear different ideas to do it.

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do i am finding problems understanding that 'IF' condition.

Comment: You may have loaded these assets from files (or the assets catalog), but once they’re loaded, the images, themselves, don’t have names. You’ll have to keep track of the names yourself.

Comment: I need to check if index[0] of all 3 arrays equal or none of them equal for example 1, 2 , 3 is true, 3 , 3 , 3 is true as well but 1 , 1 , 2 is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but you can use `tag` get what button was tapped.

In the **Storyboard**, connect your three buttons to the same `@IBAction` with `sender` type of `UIButton`, then simply case around the tag to know what button user tapped.

```
@IBAction func tappedButton(_ sender:  UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
        case 0: // image One
        case 1: // image Two
        case 2: // image Three
        default: // default condition where there is no matching cases
    }
}
```

Just drag the buttons to the function, 
**Don't forget to give them tags.**

```
btn.tag = 0
```

Or directly from the IB.